# How can I get the implementation class name based on the interface object in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I want to get the implementation class name from my interface object — is there any way to do this?

I know I can use `instanceof` to check the implementation object, but in my application there are nearly 20 to 30 classes implementing the same interface to override one particular method.

I want to figure out which particular method it is going to call.

Comment: Why do you need to know? Isn't the point of abstraction to make it not matter which type you have?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do? Maybe with a code example. This is not really understandable.

Comment: This sounds like an X->Y problem. Could you explain the purpose behind finding out the particular method?

Comment: `yourInstance.getClass().getName()`

Comment: You should start by reading this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `object.getClass()` - it will return the runtime class used implementing your interface:

```
public class Test {

  public interface MyInterface { }
  static class AClass implements MyInterface { }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyInterface object = new AClass();
      System.out.println(object.getClass());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Both are perfect answers

Comment: @Manuel Does this apply to methods? I am currently trying to find from where a method is called in Java?

Comment: Raise a new question. (short answer: You may have to use exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

A simple `getClass()` on the Object would work.

example :

```
public class SquaresProblem implements MyInterface {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInterface myi = new SquaresProblem();
    System.out.println(myi.getClass()); // use getClass().getName() to get just the name
    SomeOtherClass.printPassedClassname(myi);
}

@Override
public void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("in SquaresProblem");
}
```

}

```
interface MyInterface {
    public void someMethod();
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public static void printPassedClassname(MyInterface myi) {
        System.out.println("SomeOtherClass : ");
        System.out.println(myi.getClass()); // use getClass().getName() to get just the name
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
class SquaresProblem --> class name
SomeOtherClass : 
class SquaresProblem --> class name
```